# Prefix param in KG API doesn't affect?

Tags: knowledge-graph, google-knowledge-graph

I'm calling the KG API:

https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?key=----key-----&limit=1000&languages=en&types=&prefix=true&query=dog

`&prefix=true` so I expect to see only results with names that starts with `dog`, but I see a few which don't comply. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [Google Knowledge Graph Search API weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66087385/google-knowledge-graph-search-api-weird-results).

Internally it actually searches for prefix for names and alternativeNames, but it uses all languages (and aliases). Therefore, when you search for `query=Влад&prefix=true&languages=en`, you will get `"name": "Vladimir Lenin"` in a response, even though this string does not start with `Влад`.